# Method assertEquals(Object, object) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (String, Void)

Tags: java, junit

I have a static void method that prints out a statement depending on what string is input and then returns. I'm trying to use jUnit to make sure that the print statement is correct for the input given.

I tried to use assertEquals(expected, System.method("input"));

I am given the error "The method assertEquals(Object, object) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (String, Void)." I understand the error, but I have been unable to find out how to write my test case differently so that I can compare the two.

Comment: If you are using the name annotation param and one of the inputs has a rounded bracket, e.g. @Parameters(name = "test({index})"), then the name gets truncated in Eclipse versions prior to 4.4 (Luna).

Comment: The way you would probably do it would be to create an output stream, then the System class has something like a `setOut` method, so your method would then write directly to the stream and then you could check the contents. I can research the exact methods and use later when I have time, or you or somebody else can follow up on this in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @tradeJmark's answer; assuming your static method (the one to test) is calling `System.out.print*` for something; then you can 'hijack' the `OutputStream` for `System` via:

```
@Test
public void testThing() {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));

    ClassToTest.testMethod(/* desired input */);

    final String written = out.toString();

    Assert.assertEquals(expected, written);
}
```

Noting of course things like calling `System.out.println(...)` (rather than `System.out.print(...)`) will append `\n` (or similar depending on OS) to the end of the written `String`, etc.

Note: If you're planning to do this; I'd recommend reverting it somewhere as well.  Something like the following should handle this.

```
private static PrintStream ORIGINAL_OUT = null;

@BeforeClass
public static void interceptOut() {
    ORIGINAL_OUT = System.out;
}

@AfterClass
public static void revertOut() {
    System.setOut(ORIGINAL_OUT);
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. What is the reason for reverting it?

Comment: Generally you want your tests (or in this case, class of tests) to be self-contained; i.e. they don't leak things out to other test classes.  If you _didn't_ revert it here, but you had another class which used `System.out` for another purpose (which ran after this class' tests) then it'd still be using your local variable.  Tests run in separate instances of your test class, but modifying static variables will leak out.